# Give output of value in txt file (multiple)

Tags: javascript

i am very nooby in javascript.
I want show value of multiple txt files. at the moment i only have a code for one file i tryed to insert "for" in function "handleTextFile" and "search" but its not working. How i need modify the Code below?

html

```
<input type="file" id="fText" name="files[]" multiple/>
<br><br>
<button onclick="search()">search</button>
<output id="list"></output>
```

javascript

```
   <script>
    var Text = "";
    var Zertifikate;

    function handleTextFile(evt)
    {       
            var files = evt.target.files; 
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(){
            Text = reader.result.toLowerCase();
            };
            reader.readAsText(files[0]);         
    }


    function search()
    {
        output = [];
        document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + "" + '</ul>';
              output.push(Text);
        document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('\r\n') + '</ul>';
    }

    document.getElementById('fText').addEventListener('change', handleTextFile, false);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were in the right way. In handle text file functions you needed to loop through each files, use readFile to get the text and then add that text in an array.

Then in search function you just had to loop thought your array containing text from files and create the html you want with this text and finally add it to your output element.

Here is a working exemple with comments in it explaining things :

HTML :

```
<input type="file" id="fText" multiple/>
<br><br>
<button id="searchBtn">search</button>
<ul id="output"></ul>
```

JavaScript :

```
// store text of files in this array
var filesText = [];

// get all elements we need
var output = document.getElementById('output');
var fileInput = document.getElementById('fText');
var searchBtn = document.getElementById('searchBtn');

// add listeners
fileInput.addEventListener('change', onInputChange, false);
searchBtn.addEventListener('click', onSearchClick, false);

// all of our functions
function onInputChange(e) {
   var files = e.target.files;
   // resetFilesText
   filesText = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      // fileReader return the result in an asynchronous way and so return the result after the end of the loop 
      // so if you do it in the loop directly you will only have the last file
      // that's why I'm doing it in an other function, hope it's clear.
      readFile(files[i]);
   }   
}

function readFile(file) {
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = function() {
      // push file text in filesText array
      filesText.push(reader.result.toLowerCase());
   };
   reader.readAsText(file);
}

function onSearchClick(e) {
   // will produce a single string with '<li>text from file 1</li><li>text from file 2</li><li> etc etc';
   var list = filesText.map(function(text) {
      return '<li>' + text + '</li>';
   }).join('');

   output.innerHTML = list;
}
```

Hope it's clear.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you

Comment: @user2826395 don't hesitate to mark it as answered if it works and if you don't have more question about it.

Comment: Ps.: i guess i can`t mark as best question (because my ranking)

Comment: one question. i am trying but code is not good looking. is it posible to keep any text input in a array?

Comment: you mean keeping an html element in an array or just the text ?

Comment: only the ouputtext. so user can upload 20 files and than it keeps the output text in variables.

Comment: You juste have to remove the line were I reset the array if you want to keep adding texte files, try it

Comment: Yes i can output "filesText[1]" etc. but not in iteration / "for"-loop o,O
i guess thats because asynchron?

Comment: not in the "onInputChange" function forLoop because fileReader return the text in an asynchronus way, but in the search function you can get text files from each file with a for loop.

Comment: Oh... ye i found my mistake. i tryed to call the var "files" in function onSearchClick. Clearly. variable must be global. so i deleted var now :D

Comment: Global variable aren&#39;t that good when you&#39;re on a Big project, be carefull about using it to much